# Customise the control buttons in rich:orderingList

Tags: richfaces, custom-controls

I'm trying to change the default control buttons (top, up, down, bottom) in the rich:orderingList component. I can change the appearance of the enabled buttons by changing the default class definitions (.rf-ord-up-tp, .rf-ord-up, .rf-ord-dn and .rf-ord-dn-bt). This works, but I also want to change the buttons appearence when the control is disabled (ie when no items in the list have been selected). There don't appear to be any class definitions for the disabled buttons, so currently my custom buttons show unchanged whether the control is enabled or disabled. Anybody any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `.rf-ord-btn-dis` class for this (see the [guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.2.X/4.2.2.Final/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs.html#sect-Component_Reference-richorderingList-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters)).

However you can achieve this through CSS even without the class:

```
.rf-ord-btn[disabled="disabled"] {
}
```

This will style all the buttons that are disabled.